# UITableView doesn't scroll top after filtering through UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, scroll

I have a UISearchbar and UITableView. I display the results in the tableview that I created.

After filtering the tableview through the NSString that I type in UISearchbar, I can't make the tableview scroll go to top. If I scroll to another point on tableview after filtering and I continue to type in searchbar, tableview scroll is still at the same point. I want that the tableview scroll is at the top.

I tried these:

```
[tableview scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
tableview.contentOffset=CGPointMake(0,0);
tableview.scrollsToTop=true;
```

I call the filtering fucntion in

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
```

and

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
```

What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that wherever you are calling "`scrollRectToVisible:`" from, your "`tableview`" is null.

Try this:

```
if(tableview)
{
    [tableview scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES]; 
    tableview.contentOffset=CGPointMake(0,0);
    tableview.scrollsToTop=true;
} else {
    NSLog(@"tableview is null, I need to use a property for my tableview");
}
```

Comment: Tableview is never null.